# NPM Package publishing

Tags: javascript, github, npm, publishing

How could I possibly create an npm package by following a pattern that mui does like?

`using @ name slash package`

example

1. `@mui/materia`
2. `@mui/styles`

I just got curious since I never actually published anything on npm!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a npm package using `npm pack`. But usually this is used to pack libraries. And to publish use `npm publish`.

You can take a look at this doc to see how you can create and publish an angular library https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#peer-dependencies

To add custom name like '@mui/anything' just add this to the package.json in the name property.

Comment: Thanks for explainig is more easier than i thought that would be! Couldn't search with the right terms